# TextureAtlas issues on Desktop, exported from Eclipse

Tags: libgdx

No problems when running my app from Eclipse, but when exporting and running on desktop, all images from my TextureAtlas gets glitched, getting displayed as a black/gray boxes, as well as some weird stuff like **white gradient boxes** and **lighting overlays**.

Heres some screenshots of what I mean:

[image]

[image]

Wherever I'm suppose to have an image, thats some of the stuff I see instead.

I checked my .jar archive to see if the TextureAtlas resources made it through to the right directory that's not the issue.

app configs

**cfg.useGL20 = true;**

Anyone familiar with whats going on?

Comment: Did you solve this or do you stil have this problem? If you stil have this problem try to use different `TextureFilter`s. For this you have to open the pack file of your `TextureAtlas` and look for `filter: `. There you can write `Nearest`, `Linear`, `MipMapLinearNearest`... Try all combinations and maybe it helps. Note, that you have to select 2, one for minification and one for magnification: `filter: minification, magnification`. More on that here: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403

Comment: Can you tell us what the resolution of your texture files are? We had a problem with very large texture files rendering black boxes and such. You can use your texturepacker to limit the resolution of your texture files, and it will break the texture atlas up into several texture files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by a *mismatch* with the `TexturePacker2` version used to create the altas, and the version used to load the atlas.